# Shown Map from Sqlite in Android

Tags: android

I am currently trying to import an offline map to Nutiteq. I have downloaded a map from OpenStreetMap but that map has an `.osm` extension. I have map database create from mobile atlas center. How I can load in map view?

Comment: I try to do: http://www.slideshare.net/peterbuck/nutiteq-android-mapping-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The slideshare tutorial is from 2009, and it is outdated. Here are some hints:

- Latest getting started tutorials can be found from https://developer.nutiteq.com/getting-started .
- Latest Nutiteq SDK uses OpenStreetMap maps automatically, offline and online, you do not need to download any extra maps. For offline use case there is a guide here: https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/offline-maps
- Nutiteq supports also mbtiles, see https://developer.nutiteq.com/guides/mbtiles . Note that offline maps require Pro plan for the SDK.